# Openstack instance snapshot is creates an empty image

Tags: openstack, openstack-cinder

I have a local devstack deployment of openstack kilo, I wanted to backup a running instance in openstack. So I wanted to create snapshot of a running instance. I did create snapshot of running instances (both with API and Horizon); however, it is creates an empty image of file size. I tried to locate log files at /var/log/cinder but there is no such directory. Also, I  was not able to find such log files at other locations in root tree. So where should I find the log files (for errors etc.) ?

Comment: Logs http://docs.openstack.org/ops-guide/ops_logging.html#where-are-the-logs

Comment: Make sure you do all as it says here when taking snapshot http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/cli_use_snapshots_to_migrate_instances.html#create-a-snapshot-of-the-instance

Comment: Hi Tony, 
But I went through those documentations already. Surprisingly, I was able to find log files in /opt/stack/logs (nova,cinder, etc... ), but directories like /var/log/xxxx don't exist on my system.
Secondly, I tried with both APIs and Horizon ,they do create snapshot, but the snapshot is of zero bytes and not unable.

Answer (score 0):

Create snapshot of instance which is boot from volume, will create an empty image in glance and create snapshots of the volumes attached to instance.